# Use pointers to items in a vector, and deleting items from the vector

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, containers, stdvector

I have std::vector of some class, and in my program I have some pointers to several items in the vector, the problem is when I delete one item, for example the first item, all pointers are wrong, this is an example of code:

```
vector<int> numbers;
numbers.push_back(100);
numbers.push_back(200);
numbers.push_back(300);

int *pNum = & numbers[1]; // pNum pointer to 200

numbers.erase(numbers.begin()); // now pNum pointer to 300
```

I understand why it happens, the question is whether there is a way to solve the problem?

Comment: make a copy of the data you want.

Comment: I want the `pNum` will be always pointer to the cell that contains the value 200

Comment: is creating a function that delete the data and updates the pointer an option? Also what happens if someone deletes the value 200?

Comment: probably a little overkill, why not use a pointer? so, your vector looks like: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>`, then you will not be hit by relocation...

Comment: @nim, i should use shared_ptr because 200 it's shared between pNum and numbers, i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save pointers in the vector. This way, you separate the data from the vector, and your reference points to the real data.

```
vector<int*> numbers;

numbers.push_back(new int(100));
numbers.push_back(new int(200));
numbers.push_back(new int(300));

int * pNum  = numbers[1];

// memory leak!!!
numbers.erase( numbers.begin() );

cout << *pNum << endl;
```

It's safe, if you use c++11, to put `shared_ptr`s instead of raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a node-based structure, such as an `std::list`. This guarantees that iterators other than those to erased elements remain valid.

The drawbacks are that you have no random access, and that the data aren't contiguous.

Comment: Yes, only that `std::list` takes up more memory